# Healthy Boy Black Soy Sauce vs Healthy Boy Black Sweet Soy Sauce

Tags: sauce, thai-cuisine

Could someone please tell me whether these two soy sauces are different?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: One is sweet, the other not?

Answer (score 1):

Black soy sauce is a dark soy sauce very similar to any other dark soy, in other words richer and thicker than regular soy. Black sweet soy sauce is the same product as black soy but with sugar added to it, making it into almost a syrup. It's useful in recipes where you want to add soy and sweetness at the same time, it also makes a good glaze when cut with a bit of water.